# Можно ли вставить в HTML письмо виджет Яндекс карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, виджет

Мне нужна динамическая карта для презентации объекта недвижимости, презентация скидывается в формате HTML и её может увидеть любой желающий, если я буду использовать виджет карты это будет считаться нарушением? Учитывая то, что деньги за это не плачу. Пример виджета:

[image: Виджет карты]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Виджет содержит ссылку на [Условия использования](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_termsofuse/?lang=ru).

Пункт 2.3. гласит следующее:

> Сервис предоставляет пользователю функциональную возможность получить
> код карты в состоянии на момент получения кода, для вставки в свой
> сайт, блог, мобильное приложение. Данная функция может использоваться
> Пользователем **только в рамках сайтов или мобильных приложений,
> доступных для бесплатного открытого использования неограниченным
> кругом лиц.** Функция не может использоваться для проектов, требующих
> оплаты, или иным образом ограничивающих доступ к ним третьих лиц.

Значит использование в частных письмах не допускается.